# Why not w3schools.com?

Tags: discussion

I have linked to http://www.w3schools.com many times in the past when answering an OP's question.  Almost every time, someone eventually tells me that that was not a good idea.

Why is referencing or linking to http://www.w3schools.com a bad idea?  I learned most of my coding skills there, and I find it very useful.  What are the advantages of the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or others?  What makes [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) bad, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) good/better?

I never post link-only answers, and I've only used those links to back up my answers.  But look at what some users have said about [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com):

> I would strongly advise against using w3schools as a reference, see
>   W3Fools for good reasons not to.

By @apaul34208

> W3Schools is not regarded as one of the best places to learn
>   JavaScript / jQuery. A well-respected alternative for JavaScript is
>   MDC's JavaScript Guide. For jQuery, check out the tutorials page.

By @Andrew Whitaker [view comments on this subject at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710350/w3schools-jquery-quiz/5710362#5710362)

Comment: Linking without copying the essentials from the linked resource is a bad idea. Not that particular site at all ...

Comment: You can find the reasoning in the [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130302014219/http://w3fools.com/) of http://w3fools.com

Comment: Tell anyone citing W3Fools that they need to go read that page. It doesn't say what they think it says anymore.

Comment: @Antony: Thanks, I needed a laugh.  ("Example: Play a sound after each occurrence of an h1 element: `h1:after{content:url(beep.wav);}`")

Comment: 10 years later, W3Schools uses `<br>` elements to add space between block elements on their own homepage. And inline styles everywhere. Just to mention the first 2 things that struck my eyes when I checked their homepage code today.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

They've gotten ... *somewhat* better in the last year or so, but they used to be notorious for serving outdated, or outright *bad* information. Folks got pretty fed up with them because people would go there, get bad information, then end up on Stack Overflow wondering what went wrong. Hence, even as a 'supplementary' resource where you've given all of the important information within your question itself, links to them tend to fall under scrutiny.

There was also the issue with them continuing to make new sub domains in order to prevent folks from filtering them out of search results. There's quite a bit of history there.

There's no issue with linking to information you believe (or, better, *know*) to be accurate, but as others have noted, consider linking to official documentation instead. It's maintained much better, it often links to even more related material, and (most) provide at least rudimentary search functionality. Tutorial websites are great, but no substitute for learning how to find and read endorsed documentation.

Just write good answers that *teach*. Don't just link to a tutorial, write a *better* one. If you do that, you're fine.

Answer (score 51):

Link-only answers are always discouraged because a link isn't answering a Question and has the potential to break if the link goes bad.

If you are *supporting* an Answer with a link (which is usually a good practice), then it's always best (when possible) to link to the **authoritative** source for any given reference links:

eg.

- [Oracle for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)
- [MDN for Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)
- [Adobe for ActionScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html)
- [MSDN for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx)

etc, etc, etc

The reason being, the authoritative source is unlikely to dissappear while languages are still in use, they're likely to be updated when technologies change, and they're unlikely to contain misinformation.

Comment: Agree entirely, though I also find W3schools to be a good reference for HTML (and sometimes javascript). I certainly wouldn't downvote if the reference came from there instead of MDN.

Comment: Well, I do use links as a further reading link, I never post link only answers.  I mean, you can look at my profile itself!  It's just that some users seem to have something against that site ?!?!

Comment: I've used W3Schools a lot in the past too, but have had my Answers with links to there corrected to the relevant MDN pages by editors. I do think if the same info is expressed as clearly on MDN it is a better link target, but when links are changed to a less easily understood reference page it can be a problem.

Comment: @Godisgood Could you post some examples where this has occurred? Certainly some people may not like a particular site of course.

Comment: Here's an example of one of my Answers that was edited from w3schools to MDN: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24112428/3651800.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I've put some in my question.

Comment: Although (by my dictionary) MDN is authoritative, it is not official; if we wanted to point people to the *official* reference—well, for `getElementById`, [I’d have to give them this](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid). Pedagogically, that’s probably not the right thing to do, though.

Comment: @icktoofay Sadly there's often a huge gap between official and helpful, which is probably why there are so many questions on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @MattCoubrough To be fair, in this case W3C isn't trying to make day-to-day reference documentation. They're trying to rigorously specify the precise behavior of a function, so that implementers can know exactly what to do to meet the standard. (sorry for the necro but wanted to point that out)

Answer (score 17):

I'll take a stab at this seeing as how I'm one of the guilty parties.

W3schools isn't the worst reference, but even their more accurate stuff isn't great. The information presented isn't usually all that deep and the explanations of why things work the way they do is often lacking.

Personally I prefer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for most things, but when needed I also go to the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/) directly.

When I was brand new to HTML, I used w3schools as learning resource. I suppose it can offer some really simple answers to really simple questions and they usually top the search results...
But when there are better resources available why not use those instead?

I haven't bashed w3schools in a while, not saying that I wouldn't, but I haven't seen anyone link to their stuff lately.

If our goal is to "make the internet better" I think we can do a little better than using w3schools as a reference.

Comment: The w3fools site also mentioned http://www.webplatform.org/. It solves one problem I've always had with w3schools: ads. The fact is, w3schools exists to make money for its owner(s). WebPlatform exists to be a reference for web technologies, and that's it.

Comment: It's related to your audience. Try with this piece of w3c.org's prose on CSS color on a new-to-HTML: "UAs may vary in the fidelity with which they represent these colors, but use of sRGB provides an unambiguous and objectively measurable definition of what the color should be, which can be related to international standards." (Wait, let me fetch a dictionary.)

Comment: @Jongware That's a good example of why I prefer MDN, solid docs that tend to be a little more digestible.

Comment: Some of my favorite answers on SO are those that taught me to interpreted w3c docs. These are the "teach a man to fish" posts we should all be striving for - they remain valuable through multiple revisions of the standards, while w3schools just rots.

Comment: Based on some of the comments I'm reading here and a little reading between the lines, I think one possible reason references to w3schools get down voted might be because some people just don't like for-profit websites (if you check out the site, you'll notice there's quite a bunch of ads here and there (at least they're technology related)). On another note, reasons for why w3schools gets used a lot is because the organization of content is rather simple (I hate going into official documentation only to find that it's complicated to read). Anyhow, still a good reference for basic html.

Comment: It's mostly snobbery.

Comment: @HereticMonkey webplatform.org is discontinued since 2015

Comment: @HerrSerker webplatform.org was discontinued in September of 2015 — if you look very carefully at the time stamp of my comment, you’ll see it was written in ... June of 2015 :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey That may be the case, but it is discontinued whatsoever

Comment: And the fact that it was discontinued illustrates >another< reason why linking to sites like that can be a bad idea.

Answer (score 11):

I still see today that there is some misinformation at W3Schools that confuses coders.

For example, such confusion surfaced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53572801/5459839). At the time of writing this, W3Schools explains what happens [when you assign a string property to a JavaScript array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) as follows:

> If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.

Compare this to what [MDN has on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description):

> Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot be applied to these named properties.

#### But MDN is also not perfect

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53875596/5459839) it surfaced that MDN's page [on "strict mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) has/had a code snippet with a comment that is misleading some readers:

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
> variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
> creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"
> (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript).
> Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead
> throw an error in strict mode:
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
>                        // Assuming a global variable mistypedVariable exists
> mistypeVariable = 17;  // this line throws a ReferenceError due to the
>                        // misspelling of variable
> ```

... The "Assume" part in the comments is of course not conditional to the error being thrown. They should just have added an example declaration like this:

> ```
> 'use strict';
> var mistypedVariable;
> /* ... */
>                        // Because of the spelling mistake
> mistypeVariable = 17;  // this line references a variable that was not
>                        // defined and throws a ReferenceError
> ```

#### Verdict?

Except for the authoritative text itself (the ECMA-262 standard) it should be no surprise that other (more accessible) texts will at times be less accurate or even plain wrong. Earlier spotted mistakes have been corrected over time. Those that have a wiki-like update mechanism get fixed sooner, but are also vulnerable to temporary glitches.

One should be always careful in relying on one source only.

Comment: Also note that w3schools is closed and only the owner(s) can update it. MDN is essentially a wiki that can be peer reviewed.

Comment: There is no any resource which 100% accurate. Even you can find a lot of mistakes in StackOverflow, but those content will be updated with time since content managed by users in here... For me, W3School is one of the best resources for beginners.

Comment: Should make it explicit that your W3S example is not just incomplete but plain wrong, Every array is already a "standard" object.

Answer (score 0):

When someone asks a question, it's usually a problem that can be broken down to one or more API or library methods, constants, whatever.

On W3Schools, I usually see problems explained or "explained", similarly to how you would ask a question here, like "how to create and style an HTML table" or "how to render a list of elements to *li* tags using JavaScript".

So it sounds intuitive to link them to such an article or tutorial.

However, I find it much more productive to explain exactly how to break down what they want to do or what's wrong with what they were trying to do in an answer, and link them to the individual API or library methods, constants, whatever.

These will be without a doubt more accurate on [MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs), as it's actively updated, and in case it becomes outdated, it's marked there, and you are linked to newer alternatives.

Answer (score -19):

#### A good place for starting

W3Schools is perfect for a beginner with its clear interface.

Its *[Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro)* and tutorial notation help to keep the learning motivation.

I'm personally totally new into coding, and the W3C approach helps me better than any other.

Comment: When I was one to two weeks into python coding, I decided to take some tests on w3schools. Turns out, I spotted many flaws in the "answers" even with such little coding knowledge.

Comment: It's perfect if you want to learn the concepts only. Not for learning about how the languages really work. Once you try to actually solve a problem or make something useful, it's not sufficient. Don't go for insufficient and easy, go for good and thorough :)

Comment: Find a site/channel that's *dedicated* to teaching the *specific* language or technology that you are studying. Even better if they have "learning paths" that start with the basics then builds on top of it to get to advanced topics. W3schools is more of a "memorize these things" type, they try to cover everything so it lacks explanations, and they don't even teach you to use the official docs of the language/tech/tool you are learning.

Comment: What do you by *"W3C approach"*? W3C is an international standards organization for the World Wide Web. How is it related to W3Schools? It is close in name, but does W3Schools actually take such an approach (whatever that approach means)?

Comment: "W3Schools was created in 1998, and derives its name from the World Wide Web (WWW) but is not affiliated with the W3C." https://www.w3schools.com/about/

Comment: -1 This reads strongly like an ad or a review comment.