# Why is my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I posted a comment on Amit's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554928/joining-two-tables-but-getting-no-result/30554977#comment49187521_30554977). My comment was essentially noting that W3Schools is a resource with a bad reputation and that there are better learning resources.

Amit's reply to my comment is still there, and they're (at least partially) agreeing with me. Why was my comment deleted? I'm guessing it was flagged, but I don't see a reason for that.

W3Schools is a source of almost militant discussion, it seems; does Stack Overflow have a 'code of conduct' regarding W3Schools, where the discussion is silenced?

Edit: testing in the comment section below, the conclusion was reached by @BSMP and myself that deletion must be caused by the use of the word "google" and then getting flagged.  However, @HansPassant noted in the comments of the answer of @BSMP (now removed), this doesn't seem to be the case. So my question remains unanswered, it also raises the question why the comment of @BSMP was deleted here...

Comment: Related: [Why not w3schools.com?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/464709)

Comment: Did you link to or mentioned w3fools? It might be in the "black list" causing a single flag to auto delete such comment. (you can try and prove/disprove this by flagging this very comment :-))

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I did mention w3Fools, I didn't link to them.

Comment: let me test it for a sec, sorry if your comment will be deleted... hmm, no auto nuke.

Comment: Maybe multiple people flagged it for mentioning W3Fools? Though that seems less likely. Do you remember enough of your comment to re-type it?

Comment: @BSMP, It's not word-for-word, but I said something like: "w3Schools is not the best place for tutorials. While all right for the most basic things, for anything more advanced there are better tutorials. Google w3Fools".

Comment: I flagged your comment, nothing seems to happen...

Comment: @BSMP, your comment is gone now though. Looks like Google does make a difference

Comment: Note that comments are considered transient, and deleting them is more akin to general housekeeping than moderation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The comment was deleted by a moderator (not me) in response to a flag on the comment that it was obsolete. (This is fact.)

Given that Amit edited his answer in response to your comment I can only conclude that the moderator agreed that the comment was now not necessary. (This is speculation, but is how I would have acted.)

Comment: Seems a bit rigorous, but fair enough. How about the comment of BSMP, though, why was that deleted from the comments to this question?

Comment: @HoneyBadger because it was flagged as being obsolete and deleted by a moderator.