# Comments on the answer are gone after editing answer in StackOverflow, is this a bug?

Tags: discussion

Few comments which were showing on answer are not showing after editing of answer, this may be a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my comment deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295837/why-is-my-comment-deleted)

Answer (score 3):

> this may be a bug.

No. Comments are all *hollow words* and 2nd class citizens. These might disappear at anytime (e.g. been deleted as obsolete regarding edits of a post).

So what you've experienced there is more a bad coincidence, rather than a bug.

Comment: In this specific case, the asker removed comments they had left asking for clarification of an answer once that answer had been edited to clarify things.