# Can I replace a W3Schools link by another, authoritative reference?

Tags: discussion, edits

Like so many, I have come to somewhat despise http://www.w3schools.com. Can I reasonably *replace* a w3schools.com link in an answer with something else equally as authoritative if the answer doesn't explicitly reference something specific to w3schools?

For instance, I recently came across an answer which linked http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp simply to give an authoritative reference for the `replace()` syntax.  While there's nothing particularly wrong with that, I was considering suggesting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace instead.

Would it be out of line to simply edit the answer and replace the link or would that be overstepping?

Comment: So as a workaround for a bug in firefox we're going to edit [47K](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aw3schools.com) posts? That is a fresh approach instead of suggesting w3fools.com ;)

Comment: What's this about "we"?  I was more thinking **you'd** edit the 47k posts @rene.  My question was actually a thinly veiled attempt to create a fun extra curricular activity for you.  Are you game?

Comment: Well, I looked at the first post in that search and that question actually asked something about w3schools content. So that one I couldn't edit out. I also realize I need a *from/to*  list of urls. And with the new Documentation feature it might even be worth linking to those instead of any off-site resource, even being it MDN. I might have to hold my effort for now. Wait, those w3schools gals also do PHP ... that is bad.

Comment: @rene MDN is the prime example of stuff that shouldn't be repeated on docs.SO. It's very well written, exhaustive and full of examples already.

Comment: @CodeCaster OK, lets start our extra curricular activity then, I'll start at the top, you start at the bottom?

Comment: I think I can make this easy for you @rene - I'm looking at generating an exhaustive index of all w3schools pages for the *from* column, and then the *to* column could just be [this](http://cd8ba0b44a15c10065fd-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/mfp-en.vanillaforums.com/editor/7t/8wulw6kphyu6.gif)

Comment: @rene you start compiling the from/to list, I'll write the update script.

Comment: You know what's funny though? I actually think W3Schools is more reliable than Stack Overflow Documentation itself. Yes, that's how bad I think the current state of Documentation is for web platform tags: **I'd rather quote a statement from W3Schools that I know is correct than Documentation**.

Comment: slippery slope?  What if the links are being replaced with another site instead? Would this allow spam a way in?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Another, *authoritative* site? I don't think there's anything more authoritative than MDN (or possibly Brendan Eich's personal site) for JavaScript or W3C for CSS.

Comment: That's kinda my point. We currently agree on certain authorities. But link swapping sound like it could (maybe) be sketchy.

Comment: MDN can be edited by anyone. I'd say it's on the same level as cppreference in terms of authoritativeness. w3schools is pretty shoddy and it can be difficult to find what you're looking for on MSDN (there are plenty of resources, but most of the time it isn't an exact match). If we're based how authoritative it is on the *quality* of the source, it's difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> watch this page for instance with firebug console open for a while

Citation needed.

I installed Firebug myself and this is the *only* diagnostic I get:

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may
>   not work well with asynchronous panning; see
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects
>   for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and
>   features!

Which is only a warning. Regardless, you're going to get your browser console filled with diagnostics just from browsing the web *normally*, so it's a poor argument to make as to the quality of the website unless you have a specific complaint.

You have not made a compelling argument as to why w3schools is a bad resource (my personal opinion does not matter.) Many of us prefer to use MDN or cppreference which themselves are **not** authoritative resources by the way because they **usually** (not always) are better quality. The only authoritative resource is the spec and the spec itself can be vague or difficult to follow at times. That's just the nature of HTML and there are only so many ways to skin a pig (explain how something works.)

For all intents and purposes, w3schools and cplusplus are not as bad as they were in the past. They contain a lot less errors than they used to. If you find an error, you can always report it to them if you so desire.

In the end, what matters the most is not the quality of the source, but the content of the answer. I do not see mass editing 47k posts just to replace a link based on **personal preference** to be justifiable. If you're going to do that, you may as well edit the entire answer as I imagine most of them are going to contain bad or out of date information.

What I would do instead:

- Edit out blatantly dangerous information. Not **incorrect** information. Unlikely to happen in the case of HTML, but:
- Downvote if it contains incorrect or insufficient information and then leave a comment.

And yes, I know about w3fools, please do not link me to it.

Comment: I agree with 90% of this, but I don't see anything wrong with editing out incorrect information and replacing it with correct information. (If your editing attempt is truly invalid, then it can be rolled back.) There's a big difference between incorrect information in an answer, and a link to a resource you don't personally prefer.

Comment: There are enough [discussions on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) about the pros and cons of w3schools and my question isn't intended to address the ***why*** of this.  As the Firefox difficulties are really a side note - not my attempt to make a compelling argument, I removed them from the question so you don't get sidetracked from the actual question.  The idea of mass editing the existing 47k questions was just a running joke in the comments - as was my suggestion to replace them with a kitty cat gif.

Comment: @billynoah My mistake. I didn't catch the joke. Still, the core idea of my answer is the same. You shouldn't replace the links without the author's permission. If you comment before editing you at least 1) let them become aware of the better source and hopefully they start using it, 2) don't step on their toes if they prefer w3schools. The alternative is to write your own answer using MDN instead as the content may differ enough that you'll have a superior answer.

Comment: fair enough... i see your point and it makes sense.  thanks