# Suggested edit rejected for deviating from author's intention - what is the deviation?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I made a suggested edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30000406) for a post which linked to the Microsoft [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) GitHub repository's style guide as an example of how an underscore prefix was not typical convention. The issue with the example the author gave though is clear if you enter the page - it's very much not longer intended to even be considered as a prescriptive guide. When the answer was posted, readers were invited to use the style guide for one's team, but this has since been [removed and replaced with a much more aggressive disclaimer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines/_compare/d4cfa46778f6175a41a38bb58831427b4b345096...5bd8d0cdc8bb8fb8192199dba2b56c5b27e614cb). I made a suggested edit to change the example to being from Google's Style Guide, as it seemed the author's intention was to provide a style guide to prove that this was not convention. Google's style guide is intended as a prescriptive guide.

How does this deviate from the original author's intention, or address the author? Should I resubmit it with a more clear edit note that the nature of the wiki page has changed since the answer was given?

Comment: You should have submitted the edit as a new different answer, as you already have.

Comment: I would just close the question instead.

Comment: Also re: *"When the answer was posted, readers were invited to use the style guide for one's team, but this has since been removed and replaced with a much more aggro disclaimer."* - Clearly you stopped reading when it told you to, at the end of the first paragraph it says: *"Feel free to adopt them for your own team."*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The original intention of the original answerer was to link to MS TypeScript's repository, *not* the Google one.

If you want to correct this answer, **you need to post your own answer** that regards a link to Google instead.

Answer (score 2):

Makoto's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412047/477420) addresses the specific case very well, I'll try to cover cases where similar edits would likely be accepted.

- replacing company name due to change of ownership: Sun -> Oracle likely be ok (as part of a bigger edit, just the name change alone would not be a good edit). Just replacing one company name with another because you think it is better for the answer would not be an appropriate change.
- replacing known bad or just non-canonical links with the canonical one: replacing (non-canonical now) MSDN links about JavaScript/CSS with corresponding MDN link, replacing w3schools links with MDN (while [controversial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331841/can-i-replace-a-w3schools-link-by-another-authoritative-reference) edit likely to be approved if it makes sense)
- replacing dead links with a working equivalent (with a clear edit reason).
- replacing links to obsolete "best practice"/information with new one in *wiki answers* have a chance to be accepted. Also making additive change may be better (like "before 2020 {original links/text} was considered good approach, but in 2021 YYYY was vulnerability was discovered and now ZZZZ is all the rage").

Your tried to replace a link/company name based on your opinion about link being obsolete but the change was in a non-wiki answer - such a change would look like the author approved those links - maybe they are absolutely against anything related to Google?