# Asked question about html issues,but later found the issue occurs in w3schools only

Tags: discussion, questions

I ask a question about html issues:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883507/div-overlays-resultant-color-depends-on-sequence-of-overlay-on-w3school-tryit-ed

But later I found this issue occurred in w3school Tryit editor only, should I flag do delete it? Or answer it about the issue?

Comment: As w3schools.com seems to be quite popular, I suggest you leave that question. You already mention "w3school[s]" in the title, but it may be worth to explicitly say in the question body that it only happens in w3schools' sandbox.

Comment: w3schools is "sadly" popular, [related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) and see http://www.w3fools.com/ (lighter tone now) to get better resource for learning html.