# "I am flagging this comment as" popup is flickering on answers which are shaded

Tags: bug, design, comment-flags

Not major but thought I would log it nonetheless. Whilst flagging a comment on a shaded answer (by shaded I mean it has a negative score of 3 or more) the popup appeared in front of another shaded answer. At this point the popup looks OK but if you happened to move the mouse over the *other* shaded answer the popup starts to flicker and looks a little unstable.

Here is a screenshot to try and display what I mean:

[image]

As you can see it's not exactly a clear popup, instead it's see through. This is on Chrome version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). On IE 11 it looks fine. I haven't got Firefox to test.

For reference this is the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706382/multiline-strings-in-vb-net#comment6860663_706404) I was flagging. I haven't flagged as I'd like to provide an example for repro.

Comment: Can confirm this happens in Firefox 53.0.3 64 bit.

Comment: *On IE 11 it looks fine.* Nice try but I'm not going back Bill ....

Comment: @rene, you got me :D

Comment: That was the first time I intentionally looked for a low-quality post.

Comment: I was going to look for Documentation meta posts but then I noticed the link in your question.

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284084/312043)

Comment: Relevant CSS is `.downvoted-answer .comments,.downvoted-answer .post-signature,.downvoted-answer .post-text,.downvoted-answer .vote>*{opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s}`. The comments flag dialog is a child of the div with the `comments` class.

Comment: IE 11 master race!!!!

Comment: I can't replicate this on Chrome 58.0.3029.110, Win10 64bit

Comment: I have replicated this on Chrome 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Win 10 Pro

Comment: @NuriTasdemir that's the version I am now on. Must have been an update at some point

Comment: Replicated on Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) Windows 8.1.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 53.0.3 (64 bits) Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score -1):

## Scenario:

- Go to a page with an **answer** with a score of -3 or less (it has to be fadded, so -3 for Stack Overflow, -8 for META)
- Choose a **comment** of the downvoted answer
- Click on "Flag this comment..." for the chosen **comment**
- Move cursor outside of the **answer**

## Expected behavior:

- "I am flagging this comment as..." pop up has an opaque background

## Current behavior

- "I am flagging this comment as..." pop up is a little transparent, even if user move cursor on it (to obtain an opaque pop up, user need to hover the **answer** from which the flagged **comment** comes)

[image]

[image]

- "I am flagging this comment as..." pop up is sent to a z-index < to the "Your Answer" one.

[image]

Answer (score -8):

Changed my answer after inspecting the popup box code further. and getting the css out of all.css on this website:

```
 .popup {
box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(12,13,14,0.3);
background-color:#FFF;
border:solid 1px #9fa6ad
 }
```

I don't think chrome likes background-color being #FFF maybe changing it to the standard #FFFFFF will fix this..... 
also making sure semicolons at the end of css code lines helps the class work properly too.

So the code should look like this:

```
 .popup {
box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(12,13,14,0.3);
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border:solid 1px #9fa6ad;
 }
```

In my fixed code offering above, I made the background-color the same hex color scheme as everywhere else in the css code, and added a semicolon at the end of the border style.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, I'd say you are looking at the wrong flag dialog

Comment: Yeah, you need to try a comment, not a question or answer.

Comment: can't comment. the way they comment on this website is flawed this way.

Comment: plus the vote down and up seems subjective too. another type of flawed system.

Comment: @ACTheGypsy You can’t undo an opacity change in a child of a transparent element. If you try making your changes in Chrome’s DevTools, you’ll see it has no effect.

Comment: There is nothing non-standard about #FFF. If Chrome has a problem with that, then Chrome has a serious bug.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes - in fact, #FFF is explicitly mentioned in the [CSS standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS1-20080411/#color-units) as being a valid way of expressing "white".

Comment: besides that, background color #FFF is shorthand for the standard code and may not be fully supported everywhere.   For proper use, see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: @ACTheGypsy: I'm not sure if you looked at the link in my comment. The FFF format is part of the *CSS standard* - so *all* browsers are required to support it. Unfortunately w3schools, though sometimes useful, is generally not a reliable or accurate source of information, and its use is often [discouraged here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).

Answer (score -24):

Saving others a click, down vote this answer.

Comment: Oh, haha, now it makes sense :) These may not grey out like they do on SO.

Comment: FYI Meta has the same problem

Comment: @CalvT I was doing. I guess the criteria is -8? Or maybe something else I don't know :/ it's shaded now though

Comment: @Bugs I guess so

Comment: @James you really are an MVP

Comment: I want to upvote this post for being helpful. But that goes against what this post is for. #SoConflicted.